# NSParagraphStyle iOS - How to detect Blocks and Lists?

Tags: ios, list, block

Ive got an NSParagraphStyle object that when inspected using NSLog, contains Lists and Blocks, however there appears to be absolutely no way to access them.  Using OS X I create documents and transfer them over to iOS in a text view with lists and tables can successfully recreated and show up in NSLog.  However NSParagraphStyle has no methods or properties to access them, can anybody help? D:

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

> **Declaration**
>
> @property(readonly, copy) NSArray *textLists
>   @property(readonly, copy) NSArray *textBlocks

[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000375-SW6)

But, looks like there is no way to access them in **iOS** without introspection, as their declaration is not included to UIKit.

```
if ([paragraph respondsToSelector:@selector(textLists)])
  NSArray* lists = [paragraph performSelector:@selector(textLists)];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if let textLists = paragraphStyle.value(forKey: "textLists") as? NSArray {
  if let item = textLists.firstObject as? NSObject {
    print(item.description)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include more clarification than just a code block? (from review)

Answer (score 0):

Actually `textLists` property is available also on iOS. I don't know when they changed it, but it's true. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsparagraphstyle/1534193-textlists

Now you can access `paragraphStyle.textLists` so to check whether given NSAttributedString contains lists you can use something like this:

```
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(...) // get your attributed string

attributedString.enumerateAttribute(.paragraphStyle, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: length)) { value, range, _ in
  guard let paragraphStyle = value as? NSParagraphStyle else { return } // safe check
  if !paragraphStyle.textLists.isEmpty {
    // you got your list item
  }
}
```